# Keycloak - User Session Note Expires Too Early

Tags: keycloak

I have a custom required action that attaches a custom attribute to the user's session by setting a session note.

```
requiredActionContext.getAuthenticationSession().setUserSessionNote("key", "value");
```

The problem is that this note disappears (gets deleted from the session) after about a minute (I believe that it's the expiry of the access token) and it means that every minute I'm required to fill the required action form again.

The session itself doesn't expired because I'm not prompted to enter my username/password again. Only the session notes expire.

Is there a way to attach custom attributes to the user's session that would last as long as the actual user session (will last as long as I'm not required to re-enter credentials)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was setting the required action (`addRequiredAction`) in the custom user storage provider. It seems like calling `addRequiredAction` clears the session notes.

I fixed it by creating a custom authenticator that would run after the username/password form and setting the required action there.